# How to select a button and display the value of it to the screen

Tags: javascript, html, random, getelementbyid

I want to be able to select from a list of buttons and this display to the screen the value of that button. I have a function but im not sure what parameters to have within the HTML or function.

```
    <input type="button" class="button" id="button2" value="2" onclick="click(this)">
    <input type="button" class="button" id="button3" value="3" onclick="click(this)">
    <input type="button" class="button" id="button4" value="4" onclick="click(this)">

function click(button){
    var buttonclicked = document.getElementById(button.id).value;
    firstbox.innerHTML = "Your Chosen button is: " + buttonclicked;
    button.disabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be better to avoid the use of inline-event like `onclick` and attach the event using `addEventListener`.

**NOTE:** `firstbox` variable must be defined and must refer to an element where you will print the text.

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button");

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', click, false);
}

function click() {
  var firstbox = document.getElementById('firstbox');
  var buttonclicked = document.getElementById(this.id).value;

  firstbox.innerHTML = "Your Chosen button is: " + buttonclicked;
  this.disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="button" id="button2" value="2" onClick="click()">
<input type="button" class="button" id="button3" value="3" onClick="click(this)">
<input type="button" class="button" id="button4" value="4" onClick="click(this)">

<div id="firstbox"></div>
```

Comment: whats the difference between using this and onclick? would it not be better to use onclick as im using lots of features for my program

Comment: No it's not better at all, it's the old-school way to attach an event, but it's always better to separate the JS code from the HTML code.